# Will OTs ever act as a nucleophile and substitute with an alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

If you reacted TsOH with a secondary or tertiary alcohol, will you ever see a racemic mixture of OTs substituted products after the water group leaves? Is OTs just too weak of a nucleophile to ever substitute?

Comment: It is really a very poor nucleophile

Comment: You are reacting a very weak base with very weak acid like a tertiary alcohol, so no.